# jQuery - Dividing tables into varying lengths of sections

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a big table, here is a section of it:

[image: Table Diagram]

My goal is to make each section collapsible and uncollapsible by toggling all section rows apart from the Sum row and moving the section heading to the empty sum row cell, then moving it back to its original form when it is next toggled.

I have tried to approach this from a few angles but as I'm a jQuery novice, I can't for the life of me find an efficient way to do it.

The first part of the problem is actually defining the sections. As they're of varying lengths long, I figured I'd first need to cycle through each row and check if the first cell is empty or not. If it isn't, I assume it's a new section, if it is, I assume it's another and add it to the current section.

Then for each section's first row and cell I set an on click event that toggles all rows apart from the Sum row and moves the section title into it.

I have managed to accomplish this but it uses ungodly amounts of fugly Javascript and is very slow. So like I said, I'm wondering how I can do this in the most efficient way possible.

In essence, is there a nice way I can select all sections using just jQuery selectors instead of having to loop through every single row and inspect each cell etc? I'm happy just to know if there's a more efficient way to do it or not, but a solution would be much appreciated.

For the sake of curiosity, here is the code I used to colour the image:

```
var rowCount = $("tr").length;

var rows = $("tr > td:first-child").not("tr:nth-child(1) > td:first-child").not("tr:nth-child("+rowCount+") > td:first-child").not("tr:nth-child("+(rowCount-1)+") > td:first-child");

var sectionTitles = $(rows).filter(function(){
    return !($(this).text()=="");
});

var sectionItemTitles = $(rows).not(sectionTitles);

sectionTitles.css({"background":"red"});
sectionTitles.attr("type","section");

sectionItemTitles.css({"background":"blue"});
sectionItemTitles.attr("type","row");
```

Comment: Please provide us with a http://jsfiddle.net with your relevant code.

Comment: Would be better if you had an id on each red element and class for each section. Then on click you toggle between display:none display:something the whole section class.

Comment: That's not a bad idea, I could just loop through every row and append the relevant id or class e.g. id=section1, class=section1 and then just toggle all elements where the classname is the same as the id of element clicked.

Still a bit hacky/involves looping through every row but I suppose it's not the most inelegant of solutions.

I'll have a go, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this functionality you will have to identify the rows which need to be grouped togetherand add a  class and an image of plusminus to indicate collapsible space. On the click function of the plusminus, use the toggle() function to collapse or uncollapse the grouped data.

[toggle jquery](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)